# Syncing your clock from command line

Tags: command-line, sync, time

I manage a bunch of kiosk style PCs and I have noticed that my test machines have their time drifting a bit.

I'm curious, does anyone know of an freeware time syncing application that can easily be run on a schedule from command line to prevent this drifting?

- These systems are running Windows XP Embedded.
- They are not on a domain, so cannot use a DC.
- They have internet access, but some clients may be limited on outbound comm, it will have to be a case by case basis to config them

I've seen the [Atomic Clock Sync](http://www.worldtimeserver.com/atomic-clock) from WorldTimeServer.com, but I don't see them having any command line utility that would run silently to sync the time.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Related question: [Synchronize Internet Time in a Windows script?](http://superuser.com/questions/323581/synchronize-internet-time-in-a-windows-script)

Answer (score 9):

XP Professional has this built-in.

> `w32tm /resync`

Do `w32tm /?` for more info.

Comment: On Windows 7, when I do this I get: `The following error occurred: The service has not been started.`

Comment: @User you need to start the Windows Time service beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

There is one available for download here called [Cmdtime 3](http://www.softshape.net/download/) (download link is at the bottom of the page, listed under "Tools").