# Synchronize Internet Time in a Windows script?

Tags: windows-7, script, time

Is there a way I can synchronize the system clock with an Internet Time server (i.e: time.nist.gov) via command-line?  Preferably, this should be something executable via BAT or PowerShell script.

This particular need arises because I have some VMs for which I regularly use the "save machine state" function, and these don't typically re-synchronize their clocks when I "wake" them.  Often times, I'll re-load them to find the clock is (and is staying) days out-of-synch.

Re-synching the clock through the Internet Time Settings dialog usually works fine, but it takes a lot of mouse-clicking to do this.  I'd much rather just keep a script on the desktop that I can double-click and have the job done for me.

Right now this is for a system running Windows 7 Home x64, but backward-compatibility to XP SP3 would be nice to have.

Comment: Most VM software (Virtual PC, VirtualBox) comes with drivers ("Additions") that keep the guest's clock in sync with host, among other things.

Comment: @grawity - Using those, but it doesn't seem to do the job.

Comment: I created a bug ticket for this. Windows fails to sync with time server upon resume from sleep or hibernation.
Windows URI: `feedback-hub:?contextid=58&feedbackid=f15278d4-b20d-4a9a-9693-cdf8fbaaa669&form=1&src=1` <- Place into Windows Run dialogue if you have feedback-hub installed from the windows store

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See the reference for W32tm, "A tool used to diagnose problems occurring with Windows Time": http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491016.aspx. Also, `w32tm /?`

Use `w32tm /resync`. You may also need to set a server with `net time` if you haven't done that yet.

Comment: Okay, I did...
`@echo off && 
w32tm /resync && 
PAUSE`
Threw that in a BAT file, and set a shortcut on the desktop with "Run as administrator" checked.  Thanks!

Comment: On Windows 7, when I do this I get: `The following error occurred: The service has not been started.`

Comment: @echo off && w32tm/resync - Command propmpt says that it does not recognize command (w32tm)

Comment: .. The command I could not run on windows 7.

Comment: @Iszi My mistake, actually I just have to select command prompt as Run as administrator. The command is working very fine. Thanks

Comment: I have a mistake: _"Sending resync command to local computer. The computer did not resync because the required time change was too big. Press any key to continue..."_ What should I do?

Comment: @Iszi I suggest removing one `&`, namely `@echo off && w32tm /resync & PAUSE`, so that the command window remains open also in case of errors.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/13811519/2436175 to know how to run as administrator

Comment: If you get "the service has not been started" error, check your services and make sure the Windows Time service is running (and starts automatically).

Comment: @KirkLiemohn I was getting the same error that the service has not been started and thanks for your tip, I opened Task Manager > Services tab > found W32Time > right clicked and started it. 

Any idea why it doesn't start itself when the Computer is turned on? How do I set it to start it automatically?

Comment: @DeepakKamat, you probably need to use Windows Services (type "services.msc" in a run or search box).  Scroll down to find Windows Time.  Right click on it and choose Properties.  There you can set the startup type to be automatic.

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off
net start W32Time
w32tm /resync
echo sync complete
```

1. Copy this code to Notepad and save it as a `.bat` file.
2. Run the batch file with Administrator privileges or schedule a task to run this batch file from the Task Scheduler, as required.

Note: This required Administrator privileges and a working Internet connection.

Comment: In my case, I had to run  `w32tm /resync /force` otherwise I would get a prompt with the error `The computer did not resync because the required time change was too big.`

Answer (score 0):

I used to do it with the net command.

for ntp

net time ntp.server.foo

for windows

net time \\server

I can't recall if you needed some sort of /ntp flag for the ntp... it will tell you if you do.