# How do you change the update rate for time server synchronization on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, sync, time, timestamp

We have a file server running Windows XP, but the system clock speed is not particularly accurate, with the result that file datestamps drift with time, and this causes annoyances with software running on workstations that do builds based on comparing file dates.

Is there any registry tweak to make it synchronize more often, or, is there a command-line task I can run as a scheduled task to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahah!  XP has this built-in (duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/64071/syncing-your-clock-from-command-line?rq=1)).

`w32tm /resync`